# How to load static web resources with command line shortening?

Tags: windows, command-line

On Windows you have the problem of maximum command line characters. If your classpath is too long you cant start your applications anymore. In those cases
you need a command line shortening where the classpath is getting written into a file and the file is used instead.

What if you have static webresources which are trying to resolve from the classpath and do not use the file created by the command line shortening?

I currently have exactly that problem, in the moment where I enable command line shortening the application starts again but resources are missing / cant be found like.

Is there a fix for that?